# Command git ls-remote times out on Bitbucket, git clone works

Tags: git, ssh, capistrano, bitbucket

I'm trying to setup an automated deploy configuration with Capistrano, but I keep getting failures when Capistrano tries to run the command

```
git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:vendor/repo.git
```

The SSH key for that user **is correctly set up** inside Bitbucket, since I can do `git clone git@bitbucket.org:vendor/repo.git` without problems with that user inside that server.

I also tested the command `ls-remote` outside the staging server, in my normal development machine where I daily work with Git, and *I found that it doesn't work on Bitbucket as well* (the SSH keys in my development machine are obviously set up and working).

The actual output is:

```
git ls-remote -h ssh://git@bitbucket.org/vendor/repo.git
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

While I can do `push`'s and `pull`'s without any problem on those same directories.

What's up with the `ls-remote` command on Bitbucket? Should I make some additional configuration in addition to the regular one to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Troubleshoot+SSH+Issues#TroubleshootSSHIssues-Youridentityisn%27tloadedintoyourSSHAgent), what I had to do was to add my private key to the authentication agent. First of all, start the authentication agent:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

To list the available keys:

```
$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

To add a new key:

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/identity
```

Where `identity` is the private key file, for example `id_rsa`. From now on, the `git ls-remote` command started working correctly.

Comment: I've done this, I see the key but I still get `Connection timed out`